# Is there a current tutorial or howto document for using the xhtml2pdf python module?

Tags: python, xhtml2pdf

I can't seem to find a working tutorial or howto document for this module. Does one exist somewhere?

---

The "To be completed" section here:
https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/usage.rst

is buggy, and doesn't seem to contain working code. After corrections, this code sequence:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa as pisa
filename = u'test.pdf'
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF("Hello <strong>World</strong>",file(filename, "wb"))
pisa.startViewer(filename)
```

produces an empty test.pdf file (well, not exactly empty, it's a pdf file without content)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is heavily ReportLab based you may [find their tutorials](http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/tutorial/) useful.

(I don't use either package).